# Regex: Add text inside xml tags if not exists

Tags: regex

I have a set of xml tags:

```
<foo></foo>
```

If the tags have the word "bar" inside I do nothing

```
<foo>dog bar cat</foo> -> <foo>dog bar cat</foo>
```

If the tags don't have the word "bar" inside I add it to the end of the text

```
<foo>dog cat</foo> -> <foo>dog cat bar</foo>\
```

"bar" can potentially be anywhere in between the tags. How can I do this kind of replace using regex?

I have tried variations of the following but it isn't working:

```
(<foo>.*?)((?:bar)*)(.*?</foo>) replace with $1 bar$3
```

I am getting frustrated with this one and could use some help.

Comment: I could do this in two replacements more easily: the first to remove the word "bar" from within the foo tags then another to add the word "bar" to the end. It isn't ideal, but it gets my job done. I was wondering if there is one expression that can do everything.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern to search for:

```
<foo>((?:(?!bar|</foo>).)*)</foo>
```

Replacement string:

```
<foo>$1 bar</foo>
```

If `<foo>` tag has another nested `<foo>` tag inside, only the innermost pair is touched.

Note that the pattern above uses negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)`, which is supported by PCRE (PHP), .NET, Java, JavaScript, Boost library (Notepad++), Perl...